# Проблема с использованием Button

Tags: xcode

С обновлением Xcode до версии 9.3.1, появились проблемы с Button and Label. Когда я пытаюсь их создать, они либо растягиваются во весь экран и нельзя сменить размер, либо слишком малы + не выводиться название кнопки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если в прошлых версиях какого-либо инструмента для программирования были какие-то возможности, а в последующих — нет, я пишу разработчикам этого ПО, а не на Stack Overflow. Поскольку, скорее всего, причина // **1.** Баг, требующий исправления, или // **2**. Введён функционал, не отражённый в документации, почему это не известно большинству пользователей. Спасибо.

Comment: Я думал что я мог испортить функционал, возможно сделал не нужные настройки, хотел услышать от других разработчиков

Comment: Сергей Меньшиков, если так, то сделайте бэкап всех своих настроек → попробуйте, воспроизводится ли Ваша проблема с дефолтными настройками. Если да — пишем разработчикам, нет — попробуйте определить, из-за каких именно настроек возникает проблема. Так происходит процесс отладки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю в чем была проблема, но перегрузка системы вернула все в свое русло

Answer (score 0):

Часто бывает подобное, правда в основном в xib. Спасает метод зайти в source code xib/storyboard и удалить все строки с nil, вида типа:

```
<nil tag=“highlighttColor”>
```

А порой просто переключиться source code - editor